# Basics > Runtime > FRAME > Substrate FRAME Pallets

Tags: pallet, frame, runtime, basics

as a learner and beginner, I have 2 questions about the FRAME Pallets and especially to that overview:
[https://docs.substrate.io/v3/runtime/frame/-->](https://docs.substrate.io/v3/runtime/frame/--%3E) Substrate FRAME PALLETS:

[image: Substrate FRAME PALLETS]

The highlighted pallets as Aura, Collective, Timestamp (highlighted pallets in the diagram and linked with the Runtime diagram):

```
1. Are those pallets are necessary for the runtime to work properly? A kind of 'must haves'? 
2. If not: What other core message is this overview supposed to convey?
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Best,
Cindy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first answer 1.
There are consensus pallets and runtime pallets. Aura is a  consensus pallet. Is it important? Yes if you plan to use that consensus  mechanism and No if you don’t plan to use that consensus (There is BABE pallet for consensus also).

Second question 2.
The message conveyed by that diagram is that in substrate you can pick any pallets you want and configure them onto your runtime. So it doesn’t portray that those are the important pallets. The important pallets are the one being which fit your purpose.  Hope answered your questions

Comment: Hi Mrisho, Thank you very much! I see, this diagram is just an example that shows, what ever pallet I want to add to the runtime, can be picked and that's it. Great. Question answered.